# Finding a maximum in a defined part of a list

Tags: python, range, max, function

Being a beginner, I am not sure that I am formulating the question correctly, but here is my problem:
I am trying to define a function where, given a list, a beginning and an end, the program would return the maximum of that list between the postions 'beginning' and 'end'. Here is my code:

```
def eleMax(liste, debut=0, fin=99999999):
  if fin > len(liste):
      fin=len(liste)
  for i in liste:
      while i in range(liste[debut], liste[fin]):
          return max(i)
```

However there seems to be several problems. Here, I get: 'list index out of range'. In other versions of this code I also kept getting 'int object is not iterable', which I think is linked to debut and fin being arguments.

Is this approach even possible? Or should I try a whole different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the maximum of **one single value**.

You need to instead *slice* the list:

```
def eleMax(liste, debut=None, fin=None):
    return max(liste[debug:fin])
```

There is no need to constrain the end value to the length of the list. You can leave `debut` and `fin` set to `None` instead, to fall back to the Python defaults (which are `0` and the length of `liste`, respectively).